# How to use MySQL join/count correctly

Tags: php, mysql

So I have the following query:

```
'SELECT *, upload.id AS id, report.id AS report_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM upload WHERE report.upload_id = upload.id) AS nums FROM upload 
    LEFT JOIN report ON upload.id=report.upload_id WHERE private="0" '
```

I am having an issue with how the reports for each upload are being counted. **This query needs to count all the reports for a given upload, and return all the uploads when fetched.** For some reason every time that a new report is inserted instead of being added to the total count I get a duplicate upload. See the image below:

[image]

Notice how console (1).png shows up three times for each report that correlates to the given upload...really I want it to show up once and then the count on the side should be ( 3 ). Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You can either try using the DISTINCT keyword (SELECT DISTINCT ... http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL) or you can simply left join and count the upload.id entries, grouping by the other columns via GROUP BY (http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68ebe/8/0) for testing.

Just use a left join and count the `report.upload_id`s

```
select u.filename, u.filesize, COUNT(r.upload_id) as reports
from upload u
left join report r on u.id=r.upload_id
group by u.id, u.filename, u.filesize
```

I left out `where private = "0"`, since you didn't specify where it belongs to.

Comment: This does work but for some reason if the last row of the report doesn't match the user's IP then it will allow them to submit a report again. I think it may have something to do with my PHP fetch

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the number of reports for each upload, you don't need to join them, you can just do:

```
SELECT upload.*, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM report WHERE report.upload_id = upload.id) AS nums 
FROM upload
```

or you could do:

```
SELECT upload.id, upload.name, count(*) as nums
FROM upload 
  INNER JOIN report ON report.upload_id = upload.id
GROUP BY upload.id, upload.name
```

This will return all uploads with reports. To get all uploads with or without reports, you'll need a left join:

```
SELECT upload.id, upload.name, count(report.id) as nums
FROM upload 
  left JOIN report ON report.upload_id = upload.id
GROUP BY upload.id, upload.name
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74eae/12) with the queries.

Comment: This is for the number of reports for each upload and all the uploads

Comment: Your second query works, but it doesn't return uploads that don't have any reports. Any idea how to add that?

Comment: Use an OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN and change `WHERE` to `ON`.

Answer (score 0):

select count(upload.id), report.id 
from report, upload
LEFT JOIN report ON upload.id=report.upload_id WHERE private="0"
group by report.id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  upload.id, 
  upload.name, 
  count(1) as nums
FROM 
  upload 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  report ON
  report.upload_id = upload.id
GROUP BY 
  upload.id,
  upload.name
```

Comment: What table is private in? If it is in the `upload` table, add a `where` clause in with private="0". If it is part of the report table, and it to the left outer join